# Boostrap modal - a button has click and keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use two event in bootstrap modal (shown.bs.modal).
It's working for only click.
 `$('id').click('shown.bs.modal, function(e) { $('#regModal').modal('show');}`

But it doesn't work in two events.

`$('id').bind("keypress shown.bs.modal", function (e) {... }`

How can I use two events in a button?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add the listener to the modal itself.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
    // hold a reference to the triggering button in case you need it
    var $button = $(e.relatedTarget);
    // handler code here, executed after the modal is shown
});
```

To trigger the modal, use

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#myModal').modal();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a given element to respond to different events, you have to define those event separately.

Your example:

```
$('id').click('shown.bs.modal, function(e) { $('#regModal').modal('show');}
```

becomes:

```
var showModal = function(){ $('#regModal').modal('show'); };
$('id').on('shown.bs.modal', showModal());
$('id').on('click', showModal());
```